# Passing parameters to a function in an onclick event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically build some HTML and assign a function to the `onclick` event of a link. Here's the code I've got...

```
link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", "#");
link.onclick = function(){someFunction(myObject.id);};
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click Me!"));
```

My research has indicated that I wrap my function call within an anonymous function like I have done. What I'm finding though is that my function is called when this bit of script runs instead of on the click event. This seems to be a common problem but I'm following all the advice I've found so far but to no avail.

Any help or pointers is much appreciated.

Mister B.

Comment: That's weird, someFunction() should't be called until you click the link...

Comment: I tested it in jsfiddle, it works fine:http://jsfiddle.net/sGbjD/

Comment: I have also tried...

    link.addEventListener("click", function(){someFunction(object.id);}, false);

Comment: Ok, for starters, I think it may be the function that I'm calling as if I substitute a call to my function for a call to `alert` it works fine. The next problem, as object comes from an array and I'm building a list of links, the `object.id` is always the same so something's gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: I see in one of your other posts that you are new to Javascript.  To maintain your sanity, check out jQuery.  I discovered it about 5 years into my Javascript experience and have lamented not discovering it sooner.

Comment: It's interesting you say that as I was thinking it might complicate issues. I'd rather learn the basics first.

Comment: @mister_b can you post **someFunction** here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this alternative method:

```
function someFunction(id) {
    return function() {
        alert(id);
    };
}

link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", "#");
link.onclick = someFunction(myObject.id);
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click Me!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted works fine - I just tested it.  Here are some possibilities to look for..

1. Where have you defined someFunction?  Is it being called upon definition?
2. Do you reference someFunction anywhere else?  Perhaps that is what is triggering the issue.
3. Any reason you're not using a javascript library like jQuery to do this?  Simplifies a lot.

One debugging method would be to change that line to:

```
link.onclick = function(){alert('test'); someFunction(myObject.id);};
```

Is the alert popping up?  My guess is not, suggesting #1 and #2 above.  Feel free to post more code and we can look for the error elsewhere.

Comment: The alert is popping up. I think, as I mentioned earlier, the issue is in my function that is being called. I'm not using jQuery at the moment as I'm very new to javascript and want to understand gthe basics first.

Comment: In your comment on the main post, you stated swapping for an alert works fine.  Since that's effectively the same thing I'm doing here, this has become quite confusing :)  Could you post your entire code or, at least, a bigger chunk?

Comment: I think I'm getting this sorted now, I've put a load of alerts in so I know what's being called with what parameters. I think my initial assumption that the function was being called in that part of the script was wrong, my function was just doing something unexpected that made this appear to be the case. I have another issue now (which probably wasn't helping!!) that basically the wrong parameters are being passed to my function. I have seen this elsewhere on SO where the function is being passed the value of the last item in an array that is being iterated.

Comment: I knew it! :)  To assist in your debugging, you may also want to look into Firebug and its console logging capabilities.  Much easier than alerts.

Comment: I'm finding the javascript console window in Chrome to be pretty good too but I'll investigate firebug, cheers. Any ideas on why my function is being passed the last item in my array?